# .app files behaves like folder in Qtreeview on MAC

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am using QSortFilterProxyModel in QTreeView for exploring all the files and folders of a directory on MAC systems. Its working fine. but my problem is, In my Qtreeview, .app files also behaves like folders. means .app files also have an expansion arrow just like folders. I want to remove this expansion arrow.
Thanks.

Comment: .app "files" on Mac ARE folders. They are just displayed as one opaque application by Finder (and can be expanded via the context menu item "Show package contents").

Comment: i also want display them as one opaque application just like finder.what should i have to do this in my treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detect the property list file and then you know it's a bundle, i.e. `MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist`.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/cfbundles/Introduction/Introduction.html